RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db letting build failed
My react app build is getting failed while running the github pipeline. It was working till day before yesterday. I have a docker file which is trigger "RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db" command after that build got failed. Attaching the snaphot of failed pipeline. Any help will be much appreciated.

below is my docker file while I am using in my react project.
  # build environment
  FROM mhart/alpine-node:14 as builder
  WORKDIR /usr/src/app
  ARG REACT_APP_RUN_ENV
  ENV NODE_ENV development
  COPY . .
  RUN node -v
  RUN yarn cache clean
  RUN yarn
  RUN yarn build
  RUN yarn postbuild
  #RUN yarn install --silent
  # updating caniuse-lite version in your npm, yarn or pnpm lock file. Which 
  # will bring data about new browsers to polyfills tools like Autoprefixer or 
  # Babel and reduce already unnecessary polyfills.
  
  RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db
  # RUN yarn run build


   # production environment
   EXPOSE 80 443
   CMD ["yarn", "start"]

Not able to figure out, how it was working earlier and today build is getting failed. Look like it is getting failed on "RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db" command while running.  Please help me on this.

have you tried updating node version? 14 is unmaintained and even security updates are not made

@VladVladov, No, I haven't tried updating the node version. Let me try that. Thanks brother for you suggestion. Hope it will work !!

@VladVladov, I tried updating the node version to 16, still it didn't work. But when I comment the line "RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db" it worked for me. But I need to update browserlist, whenever I deploy the code. Any suggestion ?

Try more modern node and use official image like FROM node:20.12.2-alpine3.19 AS builder

it might been there is update about browserlist dependency or its database update u might wana check ...
Network connectivity
update browserlist
clear cache or ccache clean
debugging
alternative approachies .

Thank for replying, @bombsD Domb. But I am already cleaning the cache before running the "RUN npx browserslist@latest --update-db". And it was working till day before yesterday.

I tried with your approach, but none of them work for me. Any more suggestion.

NO i Don't have any right now
